# Jquery Datatables filter rows when a column cell is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using Jquery Datatables...

Is there a way to filter out rows when clicking on a cell? For instance if a certain column had lets say 10 rows, and 4 of those rows had the name Bob and the other 6 had the name John, can you filter out the Johns by clicking on any of the Bobs and vice versa?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please some code snippets you have attempted and examples of what you want to achieve. This will help other users in understanding the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the general idea is to attach a click event to the cells, and depending on whether that cell is a joe or a bob, you hide the other cells. I'd recommend using jquery data tables' method for hiding and showing a row. Here's an example snippet per [their docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child.hide()).

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.rows().every( function () {
    this.child( 'Row details for row: '+this.index() );
 } );

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var child = table.row( this ).child;

if ( child.isShown() ) {
    child.hide();
}
else {
    child.show();
}
} );
```